# Sacraments of Christianity

Tags: communion

My pastor says that different denominations have different numbers of sacraments. I haven't run across the word sacrament in the bible. What is a Christian sacrament, and how does it relate to the faith of an individual Christian?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrament

Comment: Welcome to the site. Though the question is fine on this site, it is probably receiving downvotes because it does not show any research effort. Basically, a Google search should have led to the wikipedia article, which is quite through. Don't let this discourage you from participating. Just try at least a google search next time, then come here if you still have questions. The site's goal is to add to the internet, rather than just repeat what can be found easily elsewhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-it-valid-to-ask-if-christianity-teaches-anything)

Answer (score 0):

The Eucharist or Lord's Supper more commonly called communion and Baptism are considered sacraments by all Christian denominations. The Eastern Orthodox Church and the Roman Catholic Church also consider Confirmation, Matrimony, Extreme Unction (anointing of the sick), Penance, and Holy Orders (ordination to a leadership position within the church) to be sacraments. Jesus only participated in baptism and The Eucharist in the gospels and that is why many protestant denominations only recognize those two Christian ceremonies as sacraments. A minority of protestant denominations recognize other ceremonies on the above list as sacraments.

The Oxford Dictionary defines a sacrament as; "a religious ceremony or act of the Christian Church that is regarded as an outward and visible sign of inward and spiritual divine grace, in particular."

Ephesians 2:8 (KJV) For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God

Participation in a sacrament in the Christian Church is an outward sign or declaration of our faith/belief in Jesus. Sacraments also remind us that we are only able to obtain salvation by the grace of God. The Eucharist reminds that through Jesus willing sacrifice on the cross, while we were yet sinners, our sins are paid for, grace & love, and our salvation is assured through faith. Baptism reminds us that through the grace and love of God we are His adopted (He choose us), sons and daughters and it publically confirms our membership in the body of Christ. By participating in Christian sacraments, we humble ourselves before God as we recognize how unworthy of His grace we are.